# Rails Carrierwave: unable to save full url with after_action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I want to save the full url of my uploaded images in a rails app using the CarrierWave gem. I update the entry just after the create action but it does not work. However, when I puts my variable, the full url appears but it only saves the identifier...

The Card controller, after_action method:

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_card, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :save_full_image_url, only: [:create, :update]

  include Shortener
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

  def save_full_image_url
    c = @card
    puts "URL: "+c.image_url.url

    @card.update(image_url: c.image_url.url)

    Rails.logger.info(@card.errors.inspect)
  end
```

My Card model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  validates :cta_button_url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), presence: { message: '%{value} : please enter valid url' }
  validates :title, :subtitle, :cta_button_text, :cta_button_url, :presence => true
  mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader
  has_one :short_url
end
```

My full logs:

> SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "cards" ("letter_id", "title", "subtitle",
>   "image_url", "cta_button_text", "cta_button_url", "share_button")
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["letter_id", 49], ["title",
>   "fsddssd"], ["subtitle", "fsdfsdfsd"], ["image_url", "10298593.jpg"],
>   ["cta_button_text", "Visit site"], ["cta_button_url",
>   "http://www.testurl.com"], ["share_button", "t"]]    (1.1ms)  commit
>   transaction    (0.1ms)  begin transaction   Card Load (0.2ms)  SELECT 
>   "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE "cards"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 44],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "short_urls" ("card_id",
>   "token", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["card_id",
>   44], ["token", "PmK5vnuCU9Dczz995fz8Ddbf"], ["created_at", "2017-08-08
>   21:08:57.625325"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-08 21:08:57.625325"]]
>   (0.8ms)  commit transaction   Letter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "letters".*
>   FROM "letters" WHERE "letters"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 49],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.1ms)  begin transaction   CoreBot Load (0.2ms) 
>   SELECT  "core_bots".* FROM "core_bots" WHERE "core_bots"."id" = ?
>   LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/test URL:
>   http://localhost:3000/uploads/card/image_url/44/10298593.jpg
>   (0.1ms)  begin transaction   SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "cards" SET
>   "image_url" = ? WHERE "cards"."id" = ?  [["image_url",
>   "10298593.jpg"], ["id", 44]]    (2.5ms)  commit transaction
>
> "10298593.jpg", cta_button_text: "Visit site", cta_button_url:
>   "http://www.testurl.com", share_button: true>, @messages={},
>   @details={}> Completed 302 Found in 60ms (ActiveRecord: 7.2ms)

When I log in the console "c.image_url.url" I get the full URL (http://localhost:3000/uploads/card/image_url/44/10298593.jpg) but when I update my entry, it only saves the end (10298593.jpg).

Any idea why I am not able to save the entire url even if I can get it in a variable before?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, but instead of ["image_url", "10298593.jpg"] it should be ["image_url", "http:// localhost:3000/uploads/card/image_url/44/10298593.jpg"]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The issue was from the `mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader`

I created a "remote_image_url" and updated it with the full url. Now it works!